# Is it possible to deploy Iphone enterprise application without Itunes?

Tags: iphone

1. I want to develop an application at Enterprise level and i want it to deployed without iTunes, is it possible?
2. If yes please explain clearly what needs to be done and how to register with apple for the entire process.
3. Any document and article and links please suggesting the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. An enterprise deployement is very easy once you have the Apple Enterprise Program license (299$). With the license and xCode you can produce IPA+Plist files ready for enterprise deployement.
2. To deploy put IPA+Plist file on an simple FTP or HTTP server and send a link to the users (via e-mail or on any portal like sharepoint). When the user click on the link, the iPhone or iPad start downloading the same way as when you use App Store ! 
   Note that the IPA package includes the App + the enterprise profile certificate you got with the license, and it is installed in just one step, like when using the App Store. You can also use the same IPA with any MDM solution for full automatic deployment, without user action.
3. Some links:

Enterprise program available here: see comment above...

Build and archive your App in xCode: use the same steps as for AdHoc builds: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG36

Use xCode Organiser to save IPA packages export though this dialog: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/distributing_ios_apps.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you can use for example [testflightapp](http://testflightapp.com/) for this. How it works and how to use you can find [here](http://help.testflightapp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, you can use one of the many [Mobile Device Management (MDM)](http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Comparison_MDM_Providers) services, the [Apple Configurator tool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) (Mac only) or a service like [Testflight](http://testflightapp.com/)
2. You need to get an enterprise license from Apple for $299/year (your company must have a [DUNS](http://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/) number). The development process ist the same as with a single developer certificate. You can deploy your app on any device owned by your company
   https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/
3. [enterpriseios.com](http://www.enterpriseios.com/) has many articles, reviews etc. on enterprise iOS development. Apple has tons of info too, of course (see link above)